# Extracting the article URL from financial websites

Tags: html, regex, xpath, yahoo-finance

So this one has been a real pain in the a**.I'm writing a program that needs the Yahoo Finance article's URLs. To make it more simple, lets say I'm trying to get the URL of the following articles from Yahoo Finance.

[image]

At the beginning I tried using Xpath in order to get all the LI,a,ul,ol tags - All Failed. It gave me wrong URL's and not the article's one.
So i turned to Regex - I used the pattern from the Expresso library for URL's, just for the record, the pattern is as follow `(?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*`.Failed as well...
Then, I used a simle CNTR+F to search for a single article's URL inside the main HTML source code, and WT*!It's not there?This is very peculiar - Doesn't the HTML source code suppose to contain all the page's data?.

- My main question - Is there any way to get these URL's by using the regular methods?(Regex,Xpath) - since the article's URL is not inside the HTML source code.

I know it is a pretty hard question and not very focused one,but iv'e read at least 100000 questions on Stack Oveflow about this subject and found nothing to help me...so I would be happy for any kind of help. Thank's :)
Note-I'm using vb.net language and HtmlAgilityPack to retrieve the html code..The image is taken from [Yahoo Finance main website.](http://finance.yahoo.com/)

Comment: Sounds like the content is either loaded with javascript, or an iframe if breaking your path. Regex are definitely not recommended for the job. How did you use the XPath, and in which language? What's the URL of the webpage?

Comment: Perhaps you should check if there is a RSS or Atom news feed. It would be much simpler than trying to scrape a portal page with generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very bad idea to try to scrape the portal like that. You should try to get that same data in another format, such as RSS, which is XML and you can easily extract data using XPath. *Yahoo*, as most news portals, provides many options of data in RSS format. With a simple search about the topic in their pages, you should find some links.

Here is a page I found searching for Yahoo Finances in RSS:

http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/topfinstories

This is part of the XML file you will get from that link:

```
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Yahoo! Finance: Top Stories</title>
        <link>http://biz.yahoo.com/top.html</link>
        <description>Top Stories from Yahoo! Finance</description>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <lastBuildDate>Fri, 13 Jun 14 16:55:08 GMT</lastBuildDate>
        <image>...</image>
        <item>
            <title>Oil’s rise not just about Iraq turmoil</title>
            <link>
                http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/news/rss/story/SIG=15hovs6uo/*http%3A//us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/news/topfinstories/SIG=13e3917ka/*http%3A//finance.yahoo.com/blogs/daily-ticker/oil-s-hitting--130-a-barrel-by-2015--dan-dicker-141207816.html?l=1
            </link>
            <description>
                Dan Dicker, author of "Oil's Endless Bid," tells The Daily Ticker why unrest in Iraq is just one reason oil prices are destined to keep rising.
            </description>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">yahoo_finance/102194239</guid>
            <pubDate>Fri, 13 Jun 14 16:55:08 GMT</pubDate>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Struggling retailers look like buyout bait</title>
            <link>
                http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/news/rss/story/SIG=15kinjdvj/*http%3A//us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/news/topfinstories/SIG=13h3m0qn0/*http%3A//finance.yahoo.com/blogs/breakout/struggling-mall-retailers-are-looking-like-buyout-bait-141750824.html?l=1
            </link>
            <description>
                One subset of retailers has been so spurned by investors that they are stuffed with idle cash and appear cheap enough for some opportunistic and risk-embracing buyout firms to begin taking a look.
            </description>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">yahoo_finance/1823439360</guid>
            <pubDate>Fri, 13 Jun 14 16:55:07 GMT</pubDate>
        </item>
   ...
```

To get all the titles, you can use:

```
//item/title
```

And you get this list:

```
Oil’s rise not just about Iraq turmoil
Struggling retailers look like buyout bait
U.S. government said to seek $10 billion from Citigroup
...
```

You should also check this link: https://developer.yahoo.com/rss/ which has information for developers who wish to use RSS data.

Comment: Thank you very much for you'r great answer!...Just one last thing..If you don't mind, maybee you can give me the URL of the rss page of All Finance new and not just the Top News,or even better, tell me how you found this particular URL for the Top News RSS :)

Comment: I searched for *Yahoo RSS feeds* and I got this://developer.yahoo.com/rss/ which has RSS links to several Yahoo pages (click on the [RSS] icons). See also https://developer.yahoo.com/finance/ and https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/miscapiRssFeed

Answer (score 1):

If the page's content is dynamically generated then better render the page with cookies or other session related things it depends on. 
 
You can use CURL or phantomJS to get the complete html page.
Once you fetch the complete page, you can use Regex to extract urls.

Comment: The problem is that the HTML source code of the website does not contain these URL since they are leading to a different webpage.Getting the HTML data is not a problem.

Comment: I don't want to talk about a tool specifically, but I will take an exception here. PhantomJS works just like a browser and the end-site cannot distinguish it from normal browser. Once a url is rendered you can then get html of the page. That should contain all the data that you see in the browser.

Comment: But why i need to use PhantomJS?I can't load the html via HtmlAgilityPack and then use Regex??Why the HTML source code does not contain these URLs?

Comment: Well! there can be many reasons why you cannot get all the url's by getting the source code. The page is obviously dynamic, it could be making many asynchronous calls which add DOM, depending on parameters like your location(IP address), personal settings, cache and cookies.

Comment: A simple Webrequest,Webresponse and Streamreader will work on dynamic pages?